# Why does my iframe application not get any keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, addeventlistener, keydown

I have a small application that is intended to be run in an iframe. It sets its own `document.addEventListener('keydown', ...)` events as well as 'keypress' and 'keyup'.
It's a small browser-based game that should be run inside the main page.

Everything is coming well when I run it directly in the browser (not in an iframe). But as soon as I put it inside the other page, the iframe stops getting any keyboard events. It still receives mouse events, touch events, window resize events, and so on. Everything except keydown/keyup/keypress.

I need help. Spent 3 days trying to fix that and still just did not understand what happened.

P.S. The previous compilation of the same react application was okay and works well with the keyboard and so on.

What I think it's a specific of the new React version (maybe bug or feature) OR it's the new funny "security-oriented" limitation from browser developers.

Please help!

P.P.S. My current dependency list looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0",
    "npm": "^7.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.3",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-multi-lang": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "wp-auth": "^1.0.4"
  },
```

and the previous (that app was working fine)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/utils": "^4.11.2",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0",
    "npm": "^7.8.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.3",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-multi-lang": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "wp-auth": "^1.0.4",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
```

Comment: which version of react are you using. and can you paste snippet of logic

Comment: @Ramusesan I've added my dependency list into the original post. Well, it's hard to put a piece of the code here since it's relatively hard-linked, but I will try to make a "minimized version" or the script in order to simplify checks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the mystic is discovered.

I have randomly added `event.preventDefault()` to my `mousedown` event handler and it has BLOCKED the focusing feature for the whole application.

Simply said, the application never got focused because of this so no keyboard events are working.

Removed `event.preventDefault()` from my `mousedown` handler and now it's all working!

Hopefully, my silliness will help someone :)

Comment: great! thats why i have asked to show that snippet of logic , where you adding event listeners. without snippet bit harder to find issue from community side.